# export datagridview to excel with interop

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, interop, export

I want to ask if there is another way to export from datagridview to excel. Because i did it with interop and it's very slow for big file. Now i want to do it with interop too but it should load data quicker.

the code i used:

```
 for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
            {
                xlWorkSheet1.Cells[1, i] = dataGridView1.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1; j++)
                {
                    DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1[j, i];
                    xlWorkSheet1.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = cell.Value;
                }
            }
```

Now i would like to export not cell for cells, but row for rows. Something with `object[,] values1`

my code for export from excel to datatable:

```
            object[,] values1 = (object[,])xlWorksheet1.UsedRange.Value2; // excelTb1
            for (int k = 0; k < values1.GetLength(1); )
            {
               excelTb1.Columns.Add((string)values1[1, ++k]);
            }

            object[] singleDValue = new object[values1.GetLength(1)];


            for (int i = 1; i < values1.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < values1.GetLength(1); )
                {
                    singleDValue[k] = values1[i + 1, ++k];
                }


                excelTb1.LoadDataRow(singleDValue, System.Data.LoadOption.PreserveChanges);
            }
```

Can someone show me how to do it from datagridview to excel?

Comment: if it's too slow you could write it directly into a CSV file

Comment: can you show me example?

Comment: How About via an OledbConnection? I think you could bind your datagrid to a DataTable in thebackground, and use an OledbConnection insert data back to Excel spreadsheet?

Comment: no, OLEDB can write just 255 chars, my datagridview has more than 255chars

Comment: Maybe http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37055/Working-with-MS-Excel-xls-xlsx-Using-MDAC-and-Oled

Comment: Interop is never going to be particularly quick, but doing the reverse of what you have above is about as fast as it's going to get. That is, writing your values from a two-dimensional array to an `Excel.Range` object. It's much faster than doing it one cell at a time. Or, as kzhen suggested, if you don't care about formatting then just write a CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

I think this article may help you much, it can export datagridview to excel with the max data of 6000 rows relatively fast in speed.

[9 Solutions to Export Data to Excel for ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/164582/8-Solutions-to-Export-Data-to-Excel-for-ASP-NET)